# MySQL Connector/j, where to?

Tags: jdbc

"First, install the .jar file that comes with Connector/J in $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib so that it is available to all applications installed in the container."

Ok, but I have 2 Catalina folders: one in work and one in config. But I have a "lib" directory under: D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\lib
 Shall I install the jar file there ("unjar")?

Thank you

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

If you put it into your servers lib directory you will see error if you deploy it to different hosts. If different apps need a different mysql version you will get errors as well. When you upgrade your server these jar might get lost too.

Better put the mysql-xyz.jar in your applications lib directory (WEB-INF/lib) and dont unjar it.

Comment: Seems that my version of eclipse deploys automatically and also there is no use to attach the connector to the project because it finds it since I put it in Tomcat's jar's directory. Someone shown me that this is specified in the .xml file :| wooo Thank you anyway;)